LINQ Where logic condition fails to evaluate
.Where(product => productPrices.IsNullOrEmpty() || 
                          (
                               product.PProduseCuDimensiuni!.Count > 0 || product.PProduseCuDimensiuni != null
                                  ? product.PProduseCuDimensiuni.Any(dimension =>
                                      dimension.PretRedus > 0
                                          ? dimension.PretRedus >= Convert.ToDecimal(productPrices![0]) && dimension.PretRedus <= Convert.ToDecimal(productPrices[1])
                                          : dimension.Pret >= Convert.ToDecimal(productPrices![0]) && dimension.Pret <= Convert.ToDecimal(productPrices[1])
                                  )
                                  : product.PretDeBazaRedus > 0 
                                            ? product.PretDeBazaRedus >= Convert.ToDecimal(productPrices![0]) && product.PretDeBazaRedus <= Convert.ToDecimal(productPrices[1])
                                            : product.PretDeBaza >= Convert.ToDecimal(productPrices![0]) && product.PretDeBaza <= Convert.ToDecimal(productPrices[1])
                                  
                          )
        )

I've got this part of my query where it checks if a price falls into the range of the lower and upper price (productPrices). productPrices is in format [lowerBound,upperBound]. I have different prices per dimension. If the product has a Pret and a PretRedus which is different than 0 , it should take the discounted one. If the product has no dimension , it should check the PretDeBaza and PretDeBazaRedus. If PretDeBazaRedus is 0 ,it should take the PretDeBaza , else PretDeBazaRedus if > 0. Everything works fine for the part where product has dimensions . If the product has no dimensions , the condition fails to check for the base price. Why ?

Is this Linq-to-Entities or Linq-to-Objects?

Why is productPrices a String instead of a Decimal value?

Becasue of this condition: product.PProduseCuDimensiuni!.Count > 0 || product.PProduseCuDimensiuni != null. I don't know your state when you wrote this code, I suggest you take a break and come back to see it.

@shingo Modified it , put &&  , reversed the conditions product.PProduseCuDimensiuni != null  first and it is still not working .

@Dai because i receive it from query params as a list of strings , than i convert it to decimal . productPrices is a list in the form (lowerBound, upperbound), with only 2 elements

OK, I think that in the top level you should have a && instead of ||
Additionally in set theory any statement is true for all elements of empty set, because there isn't a element for which the statement would be false. //Edit: I overlook this part, there is a Any, but my comment still apply, there is no element in your collection that would pass the condition.

The first condition looks wrong on a couple of levels
product.PProduseCuDimensiuni!.Count > 0 || product.PProduseCuDimensiuni != null


You would normally do the null check first as evaluating product.PProduseCuDimensiuni!.Count will be evaluated first and throw a null reference exception if product.PProduseCuDimensiuni is null.
You would normally chain a check for null with an && to make sure that product.PProduseCuDimensiuni is not null before then checking product.PProduseCuDimensiuni.Count > 0

This would give
product.PProduseCuDimensiuni != null && product.PProduseCuDimensiuni!.Count > 0

However the equivalent check can be done more cleanly with modern C#.
product.PProduseCuDimensiuni?.Count > 0

